# Insert nested object from Web Api using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to use a controller class for the first time with EF and all the code was generated automatically for the web api.

So I have an object that has some properties and it has another object. I want to be able to insert the nested object but it's not being added... only the main object. I debugged the Post Api and i can see the values but they aren't being inserted on it's table.

Here are my classes

```
public class Inventory
{
    public int InventoryID { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    public string Warehouse { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public Localization Localization { get; set; }
}

public class Localization
{
    public int LocalizationID { get; set; }
    public string Reference { get; set; }
    public int TicketsToStore { get; set; }
    public int TicketsStored { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    public decimal Precision { get; set; }
}
```

basically an Inventory is a one-many relation with Localization

this is the post api function generated

```
// POST: api/Inventories
[ResponseType(typeof(Inventory))]
public IHttpActionResult PostInventory(Inventory inventory)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    db.Inventories.Add(inventory);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = inventory.InventoryID }, inventory);
}
```

and here is my post request

```
$("#btnAdd").click(function () {

        debugger

        var Inventory= {
            "Operator": $("#Operator").val(),
            "Warehouse": $("#Warehouse").val(),
            "Total": $("#Total").val(),
            "Date": $("#Date").val(),
        };

        var Localization = {
            "Reference": $("#Reference").val(),
            "TicketsToStore": $("#TicketsToStore").val(),
            "TicketsStored": $("#TicketsStored").val(),
            "IsValid": $("#IsValid").val(),
            "Precision": $("#Precision").val()
        }

        Inventory.Localization = Localization;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'api/inventaries',
            data: JSON.stringify(Inventory),
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                alert("The result is : " + status + ": " + data);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

My question is, what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Invent<a>ry.Localization = Localization;does it work with <o>?

Comment: yea sorry i fixed that, there are no typo mistakes, i just translated to english everything

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the problem, I downloaded an EF tool for visual studio that creates the EF diagram models for Code First if you right click the context class and I saw the relation was reversed. 1 Localization has Many Inventories and it was supposed to be the opposite. Hence why it wasn't inserting in the table.

If someone commits the same mistake this is a good tutorial for Code First Approach

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx#configure-one-to-many-using-fluent-api